# Extracting parameters from a fitted function

Tags: fitting

Let's say I have written a function which performs convolution and returns value calculated for the time, t.

```
CalculateConvolution[length_, aifMatrix_, Ktrans_, Kep_, dt_, t_] := 
      aifMatrix[[(Round[t/dt] + 1)]].CreateKernel[Ktrans, Kep, dt, length];
```

`aifMatrix` - is a matrix;

`CreateKernel[Ktrans, Kep, dt, length]` - is a function that returns a vector;

```
CreateKernel[Ktrans_, Kep_, dt_, length_] := Module[{kernel = ConstantArray[0, length]}, 
       Do[kernel[[i]] = Ktrans*Exp[-Kep*dt*i], {i, 1, length, 1}]; kernel];
```

After that I use the next function to perform nonlinear least squares fitting:

```
NonlinearModelFit[TheoreticalTissueData, CalculateConvolutionOptimized[
     Length[fiitedAIF], fittedConvMatrix, Ktrans, Ktrans/(Kep*60), 0.5, t], {Ktrans, Kep}, t]
```

where the `TheoreticalTissueData` is the data which I need to fit.

So, when I run this code I get the fitted data in the next form:
`{value1, value2, ..., valuen}` which corresponds to the fitted curve, however I can't extract fitted parameters: `Ktrans`,`Kep`.

I tried to use `["ParameterTable"]`, however I didn't receive any results (because it worked for several minutes without any results, so I aborted calculations).

What is the easiest way to get the fit parameters for this case?

Comment: Hi ! Please, visit the help centre and read more about proper code formatting. Thanks !

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your description.  When running `NonlinearModelFit`, the result should be a `FittedModel` object, not something in the form of `{value1, value2, ...}`.  Can you clarify what you get?  Once you do have a `FittedModel` objects (let's say stored in the variable `fm`), evaluating `fm["ParameterTable"]` should probably be quick.  If it's not, can you give a short but complete example that reproduces the problem?  If you need to retrieve the parameter values for programmatic use, try `"BestFitParameters"` instead of `"ParameterTable"` (which is for visual inspection).

Comment: Old question again, sorry ...

Comment: Does [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/139936/44854) answer your question? If so, please mark the answer as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Make a name for your fitting, like nlm here:

```
In[1]:= data = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {3, 2}, {5, 4}, {6, 4}, {7, 5}};
In[2]:= nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, Log[a + b x^2], {a, b}, x];
In[3]:= nlm["BestFitParameters"]
Out[3]= {a -> 1.50632, b -> 1.42633}
```

Now to get `a` or `b` you can simply do this:

```
In[4]:= myA = a /. nlm["BestFitParameters"];
In[5]:= myB = b /. nlm["BestFitParameters"];
```

I hope you'll find it useful :)